# How to Remove the repeating characters that are at the same position in two strings

Tags: python-3.6

Heres my code:

```
k = str(input())
s = str(input())
x = 0
if len(k)<= len(s):
  while x < len(k):
    if k[x] == s[x]:
      k = k.replace(k[x], "")
      s = s.replace(s[x], "")
    x = x+1
    else:
      x = x+1
```

it says that the else is not working and i don't know how to debugg it. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have `x = x+1` in there twice? Try removing the first one (or indent it - it shouldn't be at the same level as the if/else)

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is much more elegant than the original one, if the strings are very long and performance is important, I suggest to keep in mind that strings in Python are immutable - you can optimize the code by using one of the suggested methods in the following [article](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/)

```
k = "String1Avc"
s = "String2Abc"

new_k = ""
new_s = ""

for i in range(min(len(k), len(s))):
    if k[i] != s[i]:
        new_k += k[i]
        new_s += s[i]

print(new_k)
print(new_s)
```

output:

1v

2b